# ImageButton Command behaves different from Button Comman when navigating to a map view in .Net MAUI

Tags: android, google-maps, maui, imagebutton

I am building a simple app using .Net Maui with  MVVM architecture . The app shows maps in some views and i used the "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps NuGet package" for interacting with google maps following the official docs "[maps official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map)". i used CommunityToolkit.Maui and CommunityToolkit.Mvvm to help with the mvvm architectrue.

every thing worked fine until i had a simple problem that i kept debugging and trying to resolve for a while and reached nothing. and it was really frustrating because i replicated the code in the same application and it worked fine while the code is almost identical , long story short after a weak i discovered that the problem happens when i use an image button instead of a regular button to navigate to the map view when clicked.

so to replicate the problem i built a simple app where i have a view with only a button and an ImageButton that's when each one is clicked it will navigate to the view with the map , the map will have a map span that should specify the visible region initially in the map

if i clicked the button the map span works fine , if i clicked the ImageButton the map shows and works fine but it is as if there was no map span specified .

this is the repo i used to abstract and replicate the problem "[reproduction code repo](https://github.com/Abdelrahman-kamall/MapSpanAndImageButtonIssue)"

these details are in the readme of the repo but i will put it again

- first you have to aquire an api key for google maps as described in the docs "[maps official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map)" and put it in platforms/android/androidmanifest.xml file replace 'the Enter Your APIKEY Here' with your aquired api key

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="ENTER_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

we have 2 views view with the 2 buttons and a view that shows the map

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
        <Button Text="MAP" ImageSource="marker.png" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" Margin="100"/>

        <ImageButton Source="marker.png" Command="{Binding ImageButtonCommand}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

i used 2 different commands for both buttons because if i used the same command for both buttons, then when clicking one button it acts like i clicked both the buttons *i know from the click animation on both * and then the problem will not arise , however if the button is made invisible the problem will arise again. this is another weird thing that happens

this is the view model of the buttons view

```
private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

        public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; }
        public ICommand ImageButtonCommand { get; }
        public ButtonsViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) 
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;

            ButtonCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(ButtonGoToMap);
            ImageButtonCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(ImageButtonGoToMap);
        }

        private async Task ButtonGoToMap()
        {
            await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync("//map");
        }

        private async Task ImageButtonGoToMap()
        {
            await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync("//map");
        }
```

the

```
NavigateToAsync
```

method simply navigates to the map

```
public Task NavigateToAsync(string route, IDictionary<string, object> routeParameters = null)
        {
            var shellNavigation = new ShellNavigationState(route);

            return routeParameters != null
                ? Shell.Current.GoToAsync(shellNavigation, routeParameters)
                : Shell.Current.GoToAsync(shellNavigation);
        }
```

registration of routes , views , viewmodels, services are all done correctly

[buttons view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR1qS.png)

```
<maps:Map>
        <x:Arguments>
            <MapSpan>
                <x:Arguments>
                    <sensors:Location>
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <x:Double>36.9628066</x:Double>
                            <x:Double>-122.0194722</x:Double>
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </sensors:Location>
                    <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                    <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                </x:Arguments>
            </MapSpan>
        </x:Arguments>
    </maps:Map>
```

when clicking the button the map shows the correct region specified by the map span

[correct map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMwh9.png)

but when clicking the image button the map act like there is no map span

[wrong map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGp6k.png)

additional info that might help , when using the imagebutton case ,if  i have multiple pages when the problem happens if i navigated to another page and then navigated back to the map view directly it will display the correct region

i know this problem is easy to work around by using a button with image source instead of the imagebutton , but i want to know if i am doing any thing wrong or am i missing some thing or misunderstanding any thing , this might help me later on .

or is it just a problem with the image button or a problem with the map i dont know .

it will be great if someone could help .

--> FOLLOW UP

i tried a different approach to use the MoveToRegion method on the map directly as follows
the map view

```
<maps:Map x:Name="MyMap">
    </maps:Map>
```

the code behind

```
public MapView(MapViewModel mapViewModel)
{
    BindingContext= mapViewModel;
    InitializeComponent();
    mapViewModel.MyMap = MyMap;
    mapViewModel.GoToRegion();
}
```

the viewmodel

```
private Map _map;
    public Map MyMap
    {
        get => _map;
        set => SetProperty(ref _map, value);
    }
    public MapViewModel() {
        _map = new Map();
    }

    public void GoToRegion()
    {
        Location location = new Location(36.9628066, -122.0194722);
        MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(location, 0.01, 0.01);
        _map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
    }
```

it still works with the button and doesn't work with the image button

Comment: Are you really going to hardcode the span coordinates in the XAML?

Comment: usually no , but even if i tried to bind it to variables in the viewmodel , even to set it in the code behind in on appearing lifecycle hook and still same result .

Comment: You can report this as a new issue on the github.

Comment: i already did that and thought maybe some one here can help too

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid posting your API key in public sites and make sure to restrict it to your application only. I would recommend that you regenerate it and follow best practices in securing your keys: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices